# ASP.NET MVC 2 Data Annotation Validation -- StringLength Minimum not working on client-side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, validation, asp.net-mvc-2

On one of my models I have a property annotated with:

```
[StringLength(60, ErrorMessage="Title must be between 60 and 10 characters", MinimumLength=10)]
```

When the form posts to the server, if it's under 10 characters, then validation fails as it should do. However, on the client-side, it only checks that it's under 60 characters -- not also above 10 characters.

Here's the JSON, note that the minimum length is 0:

```
<![CDATA[if (!window.mvcClientValidationMetadata) { window.mvcClientValidationMetadata = []; }window.mvcClientValidationMetadata.push({"Fields":[{"FieldName":"Title","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,"ValidationMessageId":"Title_validationMessage","ValidationRules":[{"ErrorMessage":"Title must be between 60 and 10 characters","ValidationParameters":{"minimumLength":0,"maximumLength":60},"ValidationType":"stringLength"}]};//]]>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in MVC 2 that was fixed in MVC 3

Comment: Can you give a reference for this, please?

Comment: I checked the source code differences between 2 and 3 after finding it working in MVC 3

Comment: isn't asp.net MVC a closed source ?

Comment: @JGilmartin you can view the source for mvc at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/ it also includes source for a lot of the webstack from microsoft.